# Boxing/unboxing costs and do boxed objects have copy on write?

Tags: java

From what I understand, Java has boxed (heap) and unboxed (stack) variables, and if I assign a boxed type to an unboxed type or vice-versa there is a(n) (un)boxing cost involved.

Is unboxing cheaper than allocating a new boxed object? And do boxed objects support COW if used readonly?

```java
class MyClass {
   public String myString;
   public Long myLong;
   public MyClass(String s, Long l) {
      myString = s;
      myLong = l;
   }
}

MyClass cls = new MyClass("A string", 5L);
Long l2 = cls.myLong; // does l2 and cls.myLong share memory or is new memory allocated here?
if (l2 < 10) {
   l2 += 5; // now l2 must have its own memory
}
```

Comment: *"Is unboxing cheaper than allocating a new boxed object?"*: why are you comparing the two? Seems a bit like apples and bananas.

Comment: I've never heard / thought of unboxing being a matter of heap vs stack, just of primitive data type vs object. Since boxed objects are immutable, you could claim they are on the heap, I guess. Your question seems a bit like a xy question to me, why are you asking? If this is about performance, I'd get a profiler before trying to fix anything.

Comment: I'm more familiar with C/C++, so often I see something in other languages and I think "what I really want here is a pointer" which you don't get with Java. The crux of my question is does Java use underlying pointer-like semantics when it can for performance. Then while I was thinking about that, it crossed my mind that allocating a primitive on the stack is essentially free (bumping the stack pointer more doesn't change the cost) so it should be cheaper to unbox than to allocate another heap object but I don't know that this is true.

Comment: @Michael `Long l2 = cls.myLong;` assigns the reference of the object behind `cls.myLong` to `l2`. `l2 += 5;` unboxes `l2`, adds 5, boxes it in a new `Long` and assigns the reference of it to `l2`.

Comment: Yes thanks, enough for me to understand what's going on. If you make that an answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping types are not on the heap because they box a primitive type but because they are objects. Primitive types can live on the stack, as local variables, or on the heap, as member variables.

What happens in your example is:

- `Long l2 = cls.myLong;` assigns the reference of the object behind `class.myLong` to `l2`, or in other words: `l2` now references the same object as `class.myLong`.
- `l2 += 5;` unboxes the object referenced by `l2`, adds 5 to the value, wraps the result in a new instance of `Long` and assigns the reference of that new instance to `l2`, or in other words: `l2` now references a new object, which wraps the result.

Imagine this example code:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long long1 = Long.valueOf(1);
        Long long2 = long1 + 1;
    }
}
```

Compile it (`javac Test.java`) and see the bytecode (`javap -c Test`):

```java
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: lconst_1
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       4: astore_1
       5: aload_1
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
       9: lconst_1
      10: ladd
      11: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
      14: astore_2
      15: return
}
```

You can see that the addition to `long1` expands to a call of `longValue`, the "unboxing", and `valueOf`, the "boxing". Like in your example, a new instance is created.

> Is unboxing cheaper than allocating a new boxed object?

As we have seen, unboxing is more or less equivalent to calling a method. Creating a new instance includes more steps, e.g. additionally allocating memory.

> And do boxed objects support COW if used readonly?

These classes are immutable so copy-on-write is what they always do.

Comment: I don't think you can really say they copy on write: you can't write to them, because they are immutable. You can only reassign the variables to point to a different instance.